# Online iframe ads with close button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, ads

This is my ad code:

```
<iframe style="display:block !important" frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=no width=120 height=600 allowtransparency=true src="//s.ato.mx/p.html#id=2225&size=120x600"></iframe>
```

My website is in WordPress.

I would like to add this code as floating on left-side and right-side of my website with close button.

Comment: Hi @user3304336. What is your question? Let us know what you have tried and what the problem is and we can try to answer your question.

Comment: i add this ad code on my website its working but i need to make this ad floats on rights side and left side of my website with close button.

here the example image i need
http://i1.someimage.com/Nn2URXS.png